# How to find all files that match a regex and store the result in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-findutils

I have this code so far:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
list=$(find "$(dirname "$0")/../temp/" -regex "(part.[a-z])")
echo "$list"
```

I want to find all files in the `temp` directory that have a file name like this:

`part.aa` `part.ab`  `part.aaa`  `part.qqk`

current path is:

```
./scripts/script.sh
```

path where files are in:

```
../temp
```

Ideally, the result stored in list should be in a form that allow looping over it line by line.

Comment: Please add your desired output of `echo "$list"` to your question.

Comment: `-name 'part.*'`?

Comment: Regarding looping over the files, don't use `list=$(find ...)` as you'll have problems with spaces and glob characters. Make an array with the result of `find`, by using `-print0` (GNU `find`) and looping over the results with `IFS= read -r -d ''` or using `mapfile`/`readarray`, or if you don't have GNU `find`, use another trick to handle globs and spaces. Depending on what you want to do with your files, you may also consider using the `-exec` action.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I appreciate it. Still new to the whole bash scripting world.

Comment: In isolation, that's a [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), paired with [broken quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). Probably try https://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex must match the whole path.

```
-regex '.*/part\.[a-z]+'
```

Note that `.` is special in regexes, it matches any character. To match a literal dot, you need to backslash it (or use `[.]`).